# how are files actually mounted using file manager in linux?

Tags: linux

I understand* how `/etc/fstab` work. I understand how `mount` command work. However when drive is not specified in `/etc/fstab` and I start some file manager, say files in cinnamon, but elsewhere it will be the same, there is list of drives in side pane. Clicking on them, these will be mounted in fedora under /run/media//drive_label(or uuid). What command is issued for mounting? How do I unmount such drive? How can I find list of mounted drives (reliably)

- I mean I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file manager contacts the UDisks2 service, which then uses *libblockdev* and *libmount* to mount the disk. (Note that a program doesn't *need* to use the `mount` command at all, it's merely simpler to do so – but any program can use the "direct" way of using a kernel syscall.)

UDisks will honor mount options from /etc/fstab if there's a matching entry, otherwise it'll use something standard for the filesystem.

The main purpose of UDisks is to allow unprivileged programs to mount/unmount disks without needing 'sudo', but it still creates exactly the same kind of kernel-based mountpoints as everything else. So to unmount the drive, you can use `udisksctl unmount -b ...` to go through the same system, or just `(sudo) umount` if you have root privileges.

To list all kernel-level mountpoints, use `findmnt` or `mount`. Both will show the options that have been used.